# What is the difference between CAPL test node & network node in CANOE?

Tags: embedded, capl, canoe

What is the difference between CAPL test node & network node in CANOE ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the basic difference is that depending on the context, some functions and events are available or not. Test nodes mostly run in sequential order, while network nodes are purely event based.
For example a test node cannot contain a start or stopMeasurement event. On the other hand it can have a main entry point "MainTest". A network node however cannot use most of the test-specific intrinsics like "testStepFail" etc.

Comment: One more thing. A test node is by default connected to all networks but can be restricted to individual networks. A simulation node is by default connected to only one network but can be allowed to access other networks as well (as a gateway).

Answer (score 0):

Network nodes are running all the time during simulation (if not disabled state). test nodes will run only if you specifically start them (if CAPL Test node), or start a specific testcase in them (XML Test node).

Furthermore, network nodes will give you access to functions of IL (interaction Layer) to alter simulation during run, specific modficiations other than simple signal value settings. On the other hand, test nodes will not let you to call IL functions directly.